# Putty connection refused on clean Ubuntu azure VM

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, azure, putty

I have recently created an Ubuntu VM on Azure. In order to access the created VM, I've installed Putty on my windows 7 machine. But I cannot make it connect till now.

At the start Putty was giving the error "Connection timeout". After I've changed the SHH port in azure from 22 to 2232 it gave me "Connection refused"

I've tried to give it the private key that I've downloaded from Azure after converting it to PPK using "puttygen" but the same error is still showing "Connection refused".

I wonder what is the problem.

Comment: "Connection refused" usually means that there is nothing listening on that port. Check the sshd configuration and if it is actually running.

Comment: Thanks Gerlad for your reply. Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the Azure provided Ubuntu image SSH should work out of the box. I further assume you have provided a username and password (and not an SSH key). The default port for SSH is 22/TCP. Therefor I recommend to check if your VM has a public IP attached to it (you can tell from the VMs overview page). If so, check if your NSG allows for that mentioned inbound traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue.
When i looked for the port that the SSH is opening I found it to be 22 not 2232.
As soon as I changed the SSH port to "2232" from the "sshd_config" file I was able to connect to the server.

It's strange that I couldn't connect by the port "22". When I use this port it give me "Connection timeout". Maybe its something with my ISP

Comment: Check your firewall settings

Comment: Port "22" was already in the inbound traffic